# CakePHP Unit Tests fails. Class not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to run some simple PHPUnit tests on my (almost) skeleton CakePHP (version: 3.5.4) Application.

I run a CLI command for migrate a Table 'admin_users'. It also creates some test cases on the fly. So good so far.

When i try to test this test cases with `./vendor/bin/phpunit /myapplication/tests/TestCase/Model/Table/AdminUsersTableTest.php` i receive the following result:

[Bad result after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUBJQ.png)

The bad thing is, that it doesn't matter which test case i run, it always say's that it cannot find any classes. Also the TestCase class cannot be found.

Am i missing some configurations? I also have a phpunit.xml.dist file in the app root folder. Could a problem be in this file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
    >
    <php>
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
        <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
    </php>

    <!-- Add any additional test suites you want to run here -->
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="App Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/TestCase</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <!-- Add plugin test suites here. -->
    </testsuites>

    <!-- Setup a listener for fixtures -->
    <listeners>
        <listener
        class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector"
        file="./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php">
            <arguments>
                <object class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureManager" />
            </arguments>
        </listener>
    </listeners>

    <!-- Ignore vendor tests in code coverage reports -->
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./plugins/*/src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

And here is a part from the TestCase file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Table\AdminUsersTable;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

/**
 * App\Model\Table\AdminUsersTable Test Case
 */
class AdminUsersTableTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * Test subject
     *
     * @var \App\Model\Table\AdminUsersTable
     */
    public $AdminUsers;

    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fixtures = [
        'app.admin_users'
    ];

    /**
     * setUp method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $config = TableRegistry::exists('AdminUsers') ? [] : ['className' => AdminUsersTable::class];
        $this->AdminUsers = TableRegistry::get('AdminUsers', $config);
    }

    /**
     * tearDown method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        unset($this->AdminUsers);

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * Test initialize method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testInitialize()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }
...
```

Comment: Is your autoloading set up correctly? If not, `composer dump-autoload` might fix it.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks for your advice. Should i run it in the app folder? If so, it tells me "Generating autoload files and Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump" but i get the same error when try to run the phpunits.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly assigning the phpunit config file: `./vendor/bin/phpunit -c path/to/phpunit.xml path/to/test.php` ?

Comment: Thank you @code-kobold. It solved my problem :)